# Limit of $\frac{\log(x^a)}{x}$ when $x$ tends to $\infty$ with $a>0$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(x^a)}{x}$ with $a>0$?

I don't know how to proceed with this limit and discuss it. Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Remember that $\ln(x^{a})=a\cdot \ln(x)$. Also, $\ln(x)/x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @ncmathsadist And.... how does that relate?

Answer (score 1):

Using the property of logarithms where $\log(x^a)=a\log(x)$ and L'Hopital's Rule, we have:
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(x^a)}{x}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a\log(x)}{x}\\&=a\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\qquad\text{by L'Hopital's Rule}\\&=0\qquad\forall a>0\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let put $x=e^t $.

when $x \to +\infty \;,\; t\to+\infty $.

and $x^a=(e^t)^a=e^{at} $

thus $$\ln (x^a )=\ln (e^{at})=at $$

the limit becomes
$$\lim_{t\to+\infty} ate^{-t}=0$$

since the exponential is faster.